# how can i figure if a vim buffer is listed or unlisted from vim's python api?

Tags: python, vim

for a tool i need to figure all vim buffers that are still listed (there are listed and unlisted buffers)

unfortunately `vim.buffers` contains all buffers and there doesnt seem to be an attribute to figure if a buffer is listed or unlisted

the vim command of what i want to do is

```
:buffers
```

unfortunately all thats possible with the vim python api is emulating

```
:buffers!
```

but without the metadata about listed/unlisted thats we need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you can manage this using just Vim language.

```
function s:buffers_list()
    let result = []

    for buffer_number in range(1, bufnr('$'))
        if !buflisted(buffer_number)
            continue
        endif

        call add(result, buffer_number)
    endfor

    return result
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Vim's python api:

```
listedBufs = []
for b in vim.buffers:
    listed = vim.eval('buflisted(bufnr("%s"))' % b.name)
    if int(listed) > 0:
        listedBufs.append(b)
```

or if you don't mind sacrificing some readability:

```
listedBufs = [b for b in vim.buffers
              if int(vim.eval('buflisted(bufnr("%s"))' % b.name)) > 0]
```